# Is using code hosting services a "safe" thing?

Tags: version-control, hosting

This might seem like a silly question, but I'm wondering what are the risks of getting your code and other resources stolen if you use one of these hosting services (ie Mercurial, SVN, etc) offered by many companies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's silly.  Nobody wants your code.  Don't worry so much about it.

It's rare that an individual can come up with something that would be world-changing.  John Resig's jQuery is the closest thing I can think of, and he's open sourced every bit of it.

I doubt that you or I could come up with something as brilliant as jQuery.  John Resig isn't worried about theft.  You shouldn't be, either.

If you believe you have something that's worthy of keeping locked away, by all means do so.  Don't put it in a public repository.